# Why does get_term() require taxonomy? Are term_ids not unique?

Tags: taxonomy, database, core

[A related WPSE question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23571/get-term-by-id-without-taxonomy) asks how to get the term by specifying ID only, without specifying taxonomy. My question is more philosophical. Generally, stuff in WP core is there for a reason. I'm trying to understand why term_id can't be the primary key for the term - why do we need the taxonomy as well? Can a single term record be a member of multiple taxonomies? That's certainly not currently supported in the API. Is there a use case where this might be desirable?

Or is the required `$taxonomy` parameter in `get_term()` a vestigial tail from an earlier incarnation of the database structure?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but i think is more of a performance issue since the taxonomy field of the `wp_term_taxonomy` table is used as index for that table, which make the query faster (even if its just a term).

Comment: @Bainternet Please take a look at the end of my A. `EXPLAIN` says `term_id`.

Comment: I think it's a vestigial tail. Logging a ticket with Trac: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20536

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've logged a ticket against this with trac: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20536

However, it turns out that for the time being it IS necessary, as WordPress currently (since 2.x) has a bug that DOES associate two terms with the same name to the same term_id! So it IS possible (though incorrect) for a single term to be associated with more than one taxonomy. See this bug: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5809

It's pretty wide-reaching so implementing the fix will need to be unit-tested very thoroughly. I'll try to remember to update this question if there are any developments.

Comment: This is *DEFINITELY* the case!  This bug bit me on a large (several hundred) multisite installation... Very weird.  AND notice that the bug is 5 years old... However, the patch is scheduled for inclusion in the 3.6 release, so this may actually get fixed! (Finally! :) )

Comment: Thanks for updating this question to choose the correct answer, Tom!  Hopefully this will help those who land on this question in the future.  And thanks for the answer/links.  Very helpful.

Comment: _Reminder to update this question_ - btw, wasn't there something with _term alias_ ?

Comment: Hi @kaiser, update it with what? I'm not sure that there has been any further positive movement toward a resolution of the Trac issues mentioned.

Comment: Currently it's target is set to _3.7-early_. Let's see what happens. What is missing? Couldn't quite follow at the end as there have been unit test from what I read.

Comment: @TomAuger This now appears to be possible - did you want to update your post? Thanks heaps for the links here btw - they pointed me towards finding & resolving this without resorting to hackery! Btw, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term is out of date but https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/ seems to be updated to have `$taxonomy` as an optional parameter. This doesn't seem to apply to `get_the_terms` yet - still requires taxonomy.

Answer (score 1):

> why do we need the taxonomy as well? Can a single term record be a member of multiple taxonomies?

No. Terms have slugs to support term archives. And having the slugs two times brings up a lot of minetraps or "wontfix"es in some permalink scenarios.

> Is there a use case where this might be desirable?

Yes: Imagine that you have terms for e.g. `size` and have three taxonomies named `length`, `width`  and `height` (you could also think about colors). But that's not supported for the reasons written above.

> Generally, stuff in WP core is there for a reason. I'm trying to understand why term_id can't be the primary key for the term - why do we need the taxonomy as well?

From looking at the table and running an `EXPLAIN`, `term_id` *is* the primary key. I guess on larger systems it might be faster to only query taxonomy specific terms using a (slow) join than querying all, sorting them and filtering what you need.

Comment: From the sounds of things then, it's either there in error (perhaps left over from the previous schema) or it is there for some future case where you may be allowed to have duplicate slugs (unlikely). In any event, I'm not sure you answered my question.

Comment: @TomAuger "Is there a use case where this might be desirable": Yes. But the _contra_ weights more. A term in tax A can have the same _name_ as one in tax B, but a different meaning for example. So, if you're querying "weight" in taxonomies "importance" and "shipping costs", what would "really heavy" then bring up?

Comment: Yes, but here we're talking about term ID, not term NAME. The ID already completely disambiguates the term from any other term (in whatever taxonomy) that might have the same name. Note that this is less of a Database question and more about why it was left in the core code.

Comment: @TomAuger It would've been easier if you followed this Q at the end of Dec. I now would've work again into this :/